# Rigid edges on video with CSS3 transform in Chrome

Tags: css, transform

I am applying a subtle CSS3 transform to a HTML5 `video` element, but I am getting unpleasantly rigid edges at the sides of the video in Chrome.

http://cl.ly/image/0v0m421N1J1U/Screen%20Shot%202012-07-16%20at%2021.57.37.png

I've looked around the internet for solutions. Some people have suggested adding a white border or box shadow to mask the edges, but I've found no luck. I've also tried setting the `-webkit-backface-visibility` property to hidden. Are there any other possible workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I played around with this a bit and I could could come up with a solution:

```
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) translate(100px,100px);
  position: relative;
  float: left
}

.wrapper:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 1px #fff;

}

video {
  display: block;
}
​
```

It's just a pseudo-element on top of the video which has two box-shadows, one inset the and other outset. This solution will only work if your background has a solid color.

http://jsfiddle.net/5SuGb/
​

Comment: Nice! It goes some way to fixing it, but it still doesn't look properly antialiased.